# Only label visible attributes using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro

I have a huge polygon dataset of land boundaries of which I only have 40 land boundaries visible.

Is there a way to only label these visible polygons in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: How did you come to the subsequent dataset of 40?  Did you do a definition query? Did you use a label expression? It would help if you provided a bit more details.

Comment: You could implement different Label Classes where you provide a SQL query and Visibility ranges for features belonging to each class. Set label visibility ranges equal to any visibility Scale Ranges you might have set in the layers Symbology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of many you could do it. Select the 40 polygons> Make Layer From Selected Features> Label them

Make Layer From Selected Features

[image]

Now you can just label this new layer

[image]